# Gauss-Seidel code not converging on solution

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave, matrix-multiplication

I am unable to get converging values using a Gauss-Seidel algorithm

Here is the code:

```
A = [12 3   -5  2
     1  6   3   1
     3  7   13  -1
     -1 2   -1  7];

b = [2
    -3
    10
    -11];


ep = 1e-8;

[m, n] = size(A);
[n, p] = size(b);
x = zeros(n, 1001);

x(:, 1) = []


for k=0:1000

    ka = k + 1;

    if ka == 1001
       break;
    end

    xnew = zeros(n,1);

    for i=1:n

       sum = 0;

       j = 1;
       while j < i
          s1 = s1 + A(i,j) * x(j, ka + 1);
          j = j + 1;
       end

       j = i + 1;
       while j <= n
           sum = sum + A(i,j) * x(j, ka);
           j = j + 1;
       end

       xnew(i) = (b(i) - sum) / A(i, i);

       % if result is within error bounds exit loop
       if norm(b - A * xnew, 2) < ep * norm(b, 2)
          'ending'
          break
       end
    end

    x(:,ka + 1) = xnew;
end
```

I cannot get the A * xnew to converge on b what am I doing wrong?

I have tried running this changing the syntax several times, but I keep getting values that are way off.

Thanks!
Gabe

Answer (score 0):

You have basically two problems with your code:

(1) You are using two different variables "sum" and "s1". I replaced it by mySum. By the way, dont use "sum", since there is a matlab function with this name.

(2) I think there is also a problem in the update of x;

I solved this problem and I also tried to improve your code:

(1) You dont need to save all "x"s;

(2) It is better to use a "while" than a for when you dont know how many iterations you need.

(3) It is good to use "clear all" and "close all" in general in order to keep your workspace. Sometimes old computations may generate errors. For instance, when you use matrices with different sizes and the same name.

(4) It is better to use dot/comma to separate the lines of the matrices

You still can improve this code:

(1) You can test if A is square and if it satisfies the conditions necessary to use this numerical method: to be positive definite or to be diagonally dominant.

```
clear all
close all

A = [12 3   -5  2;
     1  6   3   1;
     3  7   13  -1;
     -1 2   -1  7];

b = [2;
    -3;
    10;
    -11];


ep = 1e-8;

n = length(b); % Note this method only works for A(n,n)



xNew=zeros(n,1);
xOld=zeros(n,1);

leave=false;

while(~leave)

    xOld=xNew;

     for i=1:n

       mySum = 0;    

       j = i + 1;
       while j <= n
           mySum = mySum + A(i,j) * xOld(j,1);
           j = j + 1;
       end

       j = 1;
       while j < i
          mySum = mySum + A(i,j) * xNew(j,1);
          j = j + 1;
       end

       mySum=b(i,1)-mySum;
       xNew(i,1) = mySum / A(i, i);
    end

      if (norm(b - A * xNew, 2) < ep * norm(b, 2))
          disp('ending');
          leave=true;
      end

    xOld = xNew;
end

xNew
```